# How to pass data to a form in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, forms, button, modal-dialog

This is how I fill my data in a table body:

```
<tbody>
@foreach($ArrayProducts as $product)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$product['name']}}</td>
        <td>{{$product['description']}}</td>
        <td>{{$product['price']}}</td>                   
        <td>{{$product['stock']}}</td>                    
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Edit</td>            
    </tr>
    @endforeach   
</tbody>
```

But how I can pass the object that is selected in the button Edit of the product to a form to update the product:

```html
<form method="PUT" action="productos">
  @csrf     
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="name" required>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label >Descripcion</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>price</label>
        <input id="price" type="number" class="form-control" name="price" required>
    </div>         
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Stock</label>
        <input id="stock" type="number" class="form-control" name="stock" required >
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div> 
 </form>
```

Comment: You need to use like frontend framework like ajax, vue, livewire, etc. or make an api endpoint and fetch the data there

Comment: @Fernando Manuel By the way, that `<label>` be "Description", not "Descripcion" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will also want to modify this so you know the ID of the product you are editing and do error handling.

```
<tbody>
@foreach($ArrayProducts as $product)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$product['name']}}</td>
        <td>{{$product['description']}}</td>
        <td>{{$product['price']}}</td>                   
        <td>{{$product['stock']}}</td>                    
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product-model-{{ $product['id'] }}">Edit</button></td>            
    </tr>
@endforeach   
</tbody>

@foreach($ArrayProducts as $product)
<div class="model" id="product-model-{{ $product['id'] }}">
    <form method="PUT" action="productos">
    @csrf     
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="name" required value="{{ $product['name'] }}">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label >Descripcion</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" required value="{{ $product['description'] }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>price</label>
        <input id="price" type="number" class="form-control" name="price" required value="{{ $product['price'] }}">
    </div>         
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Stock</label>
        <input id="stock" type="number" class="form-control" name="stock" required  value="{{ $product['stock'] }}">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
     </div> 
  </form>
</div>
@endforeach
```